# PyCharm: Unable to run tests 'All in folder'

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

I am trying to run my whole test suite in PyCharm.   All of the test files are in a single folder.  I can run the files individually, but when I create a run configuration with 'All in folder' PyCharm is unable to find any tests.

The messages logged are:

```
C:\Python36\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2016.3.2\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Users\John\PycharmProjects\Kojak\tests\_args_separator_.*\.py$ true
Testing started at 14:56 ...

Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

I noticed the `_args_separator_` in the path, so what is that all about?

I am running under Windows 7 with PyCharm 2016.3 and Python 2.6

Comment: Are you using `py.test`?

Comment: I'm just using `import unittest`, if that answers your question.  This is my fourth week working with Python and my first with unittest.  I don't use or import `py.test` to my knowledge.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear.  In PyCharm in the run configuration, there is the ability to select the test type to run.  What type are you running?

Comment: It looks to be the `Unittests` type.  Under Defaults I see listed Unittests, Doctests, Nosetests, Py.test, and Attests.  I am definitely using the Unittests template

Comment: I use `Py.test`.  Both it and `Nosetest` will often do a better job of *finding* your test cases. GL.

Comment: OK, thanks!  I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me if I select Nosetests when creating the Run/Debug Configuration for Python tests. You will also need to pip install nose. (I am running PyCharm 2017.1 but not sure if that is necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Using the default test configuration did not work for me. The following does run all test files in a test directory.

1. In the Edit Configurations menu, select the "+" for a new configuration.
2. Select the Python Tests -> Unittests configuration template.
3. Enter your test directory in the input for Target and Working directory.
4. Enter *.py as the Pattern input. This is **the key step**.
5. Choose OK
   Run your new test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution is to use the latest release of PyCharm (2017.1 EAP at this writing).  All of the test files must reside in the same folder; PyCharm will not discover tests in subfolders.

Comment: To make tests in subfolder "discoverable" you need to transform that folders into _module_, just adding a ``__init__.py`` file into them.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pycharm set unit test from a sub folder]

I had a similar issue. I could not run a unit test if my tests were saved in a sub folder. This fixed the issue.