# How to force Pycharm to run all unit tests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pycharm

I have a single unit test file, and I can run tests within Pycharm. Fine. However, it seems that Pycharm skips tests based on some criteria regarding code change. Something like, if the code in a test method hasn't changed, and/or if the code that a particular test method is testing hasn't changed, it won't run the test. This has caused a lot of pain, and has let a bug fall through that wasn't caught until much later on. So my question is, how to stop Pycharm from automatically skipping tests and force it to run all tests?

Why is skipping tests the default behaviour anyway? This seems absolutely outrageous to me, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

**EDIT**
Oops my bad. I ran the tests by pressing the keyboard shortcut control-shift-R on my Mac OS, which normally runs a Python script, but it doesn't actually run the whole test file, and only runs a single test (where the caret is) instead. This (keyboard shortcut having different behaviours) is a little bit misleading in my opinion, but regardless, my description of the problem is wrong and I was wrong. **Sorry!**

Comment: Here's another approach to running all tests in a directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840689/3357812

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all your test methods staring with a `test_`.

Usually I have 2 Tests configurations: **All** and **Current**.

[image]
[image]

`tests` folder is located in the root of PyCharm project

I use python path to specify certain test to run.
You can easily copy the reference to certain test
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't understand how you have answered my questions. I have no problems with test discovery. I have named my tests correctly and I know how unittest works. Pycharm can see the tests, and will run them if Pycharm thinks the relevant code has changed. The problem is, Pycharm does not run tests if no relevant code has changed. I wish to change this (ridiculous) behaviour, and force Pycharm to run all tests regardless of whether any code has changed.

Comment: Also, wow you managed to make your Pycharm look like Sublime!

Comment: Oh I think I see my mistake now.

Comment: @Ray You can use this color schema too, it's customized Monokai https://gist.github.com/jogspokoen/7a8b700ceeed7945875496d00ae85795